# How can I round time on one decimal millisecond in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am just wondering how I can round the milliseconds to one decimal. For example: '12:23:47.5'

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time = t.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"[:-1])
print(current_time)
```

For some reason when I change [:-1] to [:-3] it works but I want just one decimal in the milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `[:-1]` in your code refers to the format string itself, it removed the last char (the `f`) from it.

you should use it outside the call to strftime: `current_time = t.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5]`

Comment: Thank you, it helped. By the way, how can I use the '%f' as a variable later?
```
%f += 1
```

Comment: the format string is just to print the datetime. to change the value check out the docs for `datetime`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html